# Cobertura code coverage for failed tests

Tags: maven, code-coverage, cobertura

I wanted to understand if the Cobertura tool shows the line coverage of code for junit tests that have failed?

Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: Don't you see the line during the reports where it has failed and the line number? Or what is the purpose in relationship with code coverage?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, up until the line where the assertion failed. However, if a test is broken (e.g. it won't compile) then there's no way to run the test, hence there's no codecoverage possible.